# Data Table in chart cell formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts, format

I have two similar charts with similar data tables in each. The only difference is that one chart runs for a longer period (i.e. more data points).

The issue I am having is in the formatting of the cells in the data table, as shown in the below pictures:

**Table 1 with fewer data points:**

[image: Table 1]

**Table 2 with greater data points:**

[image: Tabel 2]

As you can see the columns are squashed together and you cannot read the values in the cells in Table 2 like you can in Table 1. I have not found a way to format the cells or text that is in the inserted data table.

When trying to edit the data table these are the only options I get from using a right click and selecting "Format Data Table".

[image: Chart Options]

The table was originally added by using Excel's built in function as seen here:

[image: Data Table Menu]

ETA: I have found that I can hide cells on the data source sheet to reduce the number of points showing in the data table. This helps, but does not fully solve the problem.

**Is there a way to fix this, or are there simply too many data points?**

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Yes you've many data, and fitting that many text on small place won't work. You may increase the width of chart, change text direction to vertical, decrease font...

Comment: @MátéJuhász by correct, I mean "fix". I can't seem to find any options to change any formatting of the cells.

Comment: google for that, you'll find a lot of suggestions.

Comment: @MátéJuhász As I have already done that and not found a solution that works, I turn to the Stack. I find SE to provide better answers anyway... If you have a google search result that can help I would gladly see it as comment or if you want, make an answer out of it!

Comment: Can you not just widen the columns? What have you tried, can you be more explicit?

Comment: @BruceWayne I have added some other details. hope it helps

Comment: If you widen the columns though, does that get the text visible, or "fix" it at all? or does it not do anything?

Comment: @BruceWayne That's the problem I don't see any way or option to widen those cloumns. I believe it auto scales with the chart size.

Comment: @Skooba you can't even go to the column "headers" and widen them? Surely you could widen with VBA, ie `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").ColumnWidth = .ColumnWidth * 2`?